# java.lang.IllegalStateException: No EJB receiver available for handling

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb

I'm attempting to call a remote method belonging to an EJB.

I've started the server with the following command:

```
$ bin/standalone.sh --server-config=standalone-ha.xml -Djboss.node.name=node1
```

From what I understand the default socket binding port is 9999 for this server.
The deployed ejb remote and home interface can be seen here (sorry for the link - I don't have the proper rating to post images on stack overflow):

http://www.rakkatak.com/so/stackoverflow_question_ejb_img1.png

Here is the EJB:

```
package org.jboss.as.quickstarts.cluster.hasingleton.service.ejb;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import org.jboss.as.server.CurrentServiceContainer;
import org.jboss.logging.Logger;
import org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceController;

@Stateless
public class ServiceAccessBean implements ServiceAccess {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ServiceAccessBean.class);

    public String getNodeNameOfTimerService() {
        LOGGER.info("Method getNodeNameOfTimerService() is invoked");
        return "test";
    }
}
```

And the interface:

```
package org.jboss.as.quickstarts.cluster.hasingleton.service.ejb;

import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface ServiceAccess {
    String getNodeNameOfTimerService();
}
```

Within my client jar, I've placed jboss-ejb-client.properties in the classpath and it looks like this:

```
remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=false
remote.connections=node1
remote.connection.node1.host=localhost
remote.connection.node1.port = 9999
remote.connection.node1.connect.timeout = 500
remote.connection.node1.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false
```

And here is the code invoking the ejb method:

```
final Hashtable<String, String> jndiProperties = new Hashtable<String, String>();
            jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
final Context context = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);
String lookupName = "ejb:/jboss-cluster-ha-singleton-service/ServiceAccessBean!" + ServiceAccess.class.getName();
System.out.println("Lookup Bean name is " + lookupName);
ServiceAccess accessBean = (ServiceAccess) context.lookup(lookupName);
accessBean.getNodeNameOfTimerService();
```

Unfortunately when this code is invoked, I'm getting the following exception which occurs when accessBean.getNodeNameOfTimerService() is called.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: EJBCLIENT000025: No EJB receiver available for handling [appName:, moduleName:jboss-as-cluster-ha-singleton-service, distinctName:] combination for invocation context org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext@47dc7ae2
```

Please let me know if anything above looks incorrect. Thank you!

Comment: i think your `lookup` name is wrong, instead of `jboss-as-cluster-ha-singleton-service` try `jboss-cluster-ha-singleton-service`

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Thank you for catching my typo Sajan!

Comment: So did that solve the issue, i still see the error

Comment: I fixed the typo in the code snippet above. Thanks again.